# How to get rid of "EU Elections" Ad in Google Chrome new page

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has added an ad to the bottom of "new tab" page. Is there a way
to get rid of it? The ad is overlaid on the theme, it's not a part of the theme.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search `chrome://flags` for "NTP" (New Tab Page).

Enable `#use-google-local-ntp`, then disable `#promos-on-local-ntp`.

(The first option forces Chrome to use a locally hosted (internal) copy of the new-tab page as opposed to trying to use an online version. This will probably load faster, and it also used to have more customization flags, e.g. you can also disable Google Doodles in it.)

Comment: I didn't actually expect this to work, but it it does, great.

Comment: `#use-google-local-ntp` is no longer available now.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. All you can do is wait until this event passes.